# Graphic from a graphic in image format?

Tags: images, graphs, graphic-design

I hope you can help me. I have the following problem: I have a graph (x-axis, y-axis) in image format and I can not build it again, I would like to know if it is possible that from that image I can give them the values, I mean, I would like to know if there is any program to coordinate a graph previously made and that is in image format.

---

An example, if I have this image:

[f(x) exemple](https://i.stack.imgur.com/N5lkC.gif)

what I want to know is if there's any program that gives you the values that are coordinated on that image.

Thanks!

Comment: https://superuser.com/questions/93639/program-for-reading-data-off-scanned-graphs

Answer (score 2, accepted):

this is virtually impossible, the information got lost when the export to an image was done. 
if you still know a little bit about the graph you can try to make a fit.
here is a free [online tool](https://mycurvefit.com/) that can do this